# Mapping Non-Numeric Values in Pandas Series within a Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, maps

I started with a DataFrame with about 88 columns that contain columns labeled with strings `Employee_Id, Payroll_Id, etc` for example.
Within this DataFrame I'm accessing each column as a Series. Some of the Series contain mixed datatypes (ints, strings, NaN, etc). So some of the Series are "object" data type. I need to convert all the values in the DataFrame to Numeric types, and so about 16 of the 88 need to be converted from a Series with object dtype to int/float64 dtype.

I have a process to map each unique cell value in the Series to integers, excluding 0.

However, I get the following error when I try to perform the numeric mapping of unique values in the Series in a loop!
: **InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects**

Here's a code example:

```
def mapper(series):
    
    # create a set from items in the series 
    series_set = set(series)
    
    # create a mapping dictionary
    # for each item in the set, map it to an integer value, avoid placing 0 as 0 will fill in for NaN
    mapping_dict = {
        item:index+1 for index,item in enumerate(series_set)
    }
    
    # map the series to the mapping dictionary
    mapped_series = series.map(mapping_dict)
    
    mapped_series.rename(series.name+'_mapped',inplace=True)
    
    # return the mapped series 
    return mapped_series

Basic loop...
for series in mapped_these_series:
    mapper(series)
```

```
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py:852, in IndexOpsMixin._map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
    848     return cat.map(mapper)
    850 values = self._values
--> 852 indexer = mapper.index.get_indexer(values)
    853 new_values = algorithms.take_nd(mapper._values, indexer)
    855 return new_values

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3721, in Index.get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   3718 self._check_indexing_method(method, limit, tolerance)
   3720 if not self._index_as_unique:
-> 3721     raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
   3723 if len(target) == 0:
   3724     return np.array([], dtype=np.intp)

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I read elsewhere that this error is caused by columns with the same name. I tried renaming the column in place, but still get the same error.
Any ideas what causes this or why this would happen when modifying a DataFrame's Series(es) within a loop? The app gets through 2 of the 11 that I need to convert to numerics, and then errors out!

Comment: Can't you rename these columns before the operation? (.e.g `df.columns = ['name1', 'name2', ....]`)

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but why not just selecting all the columns you want, by name "df[['bla','bla']]" or by index range "df.iloc[:,5:10]" and then ".astype('int64')" or whatever type you want?

Comment: Right @Drakax. I tried this, but because there are "uneven" datatypes within each Series some of them can't be cast to float64/int. For example, some types are string, but others are NaN, or object. So .astype errors out as well.

Comment: Good suggestion... @rafaelc. Tried this, but to no avail.

Comment: Well, without having access to your df, hard to guess, but I think you should definitely give "pandas.to_numeric" a try with error set to "ignore", doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Comment: I wish it was that simple. Again, since there are mixed datatypes in Series within the dataframe functions like `to_numeric` do not work in these cases. I have a solution and will update this question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue was indices. Just as the error says Reindexing/Indexing occurs when Series' values are modified with `series.map()`. This was a conflict for pandas because in my situation the data structure used to map a Series contained incrementing values from 1 to n.
i.e.

```
{
 1:'value',
 2: 'value',
 3: 'value'
 ...
}
```

Series.map() wants to use the key in this dict structure as an index for which the values in the dict are mapped. As the error said, Reindexing is only allowed with **unique index values**. It was not possible to map multiple Series with incrementing, numeric indices. So the solution with series.map() was not sufficient.

Solution:

```
# Still create the same data structure to be used to map the Series' values
     def mapper(series):

        # create a set from items in the series 
        series_set = set(series)

        # create a mapping dictionary
        mapping_data_structure = {
            item:index+1 for index,item in enumerate(series_set)
        }
        
        return mapping_data_structure

# Reassign the individual cell values in the Series according to their corresponding value in the mapping data structure.

    def update_df():
        
        for column in columns_to_convert:
            
            # select each column of the dataframe as Series
            series = DataFrame[column]

            # enumerate the values of each Series
            for n,cell_value in enumerate(series):

                # for each cell value in Series...
                # map and assign the cell value to the corresponding value in the mapping data structure {'value_1':1,'value_2':2}
                # IOW get the key... assign the value based on the key, where 'key' is a reference to a value in the mapping data structure
                key = mapping_data_structure[series.name][cell_value]
                series.at[n] = key
```

Voila! Now mixed datatypes in a DataFrame are no problem because they can be mapped to numeric types, or to whatever dtype you need for your use case.

BTW: In this situation, I only needed to convert certain columns to numeric types. Hence some extra `for` loops.